# Using attribute in index array method to find index always returning nil in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, variables, ruby-2.1

Here is a simple index search based on an instance attribute for an array element:

```
chips = [Chip.new(:white), Chip.new(:black)]
color = :white
idx = chips.index { |chip| chip.color == color }
```

This always returns nil no matter what values are in the `@chips` array and no matter what the local variable `color` is set to. This still holds true if `color` is replaced with an explicit symbol such as `:white`, which is an example index expected to be found.

This is the class declaration:

```
class Chip
   attr_reader :color, :value

   def initialize(color)
     @color = color

     case color
     when :white
      @value = 1
     when :red
      @value = 5
     when :green
      @value = 25
     when :black
      @value = 100
     end
   end
end
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is occuring?

Comment: What type is `color`?

Comment: Try `@chips.each{|chip| p chip.color}` and see what you get.

Comment: The example works when using "p". However, it only tentatively solves the problem. I do not need output because the array I am searching through is relatively large.

Comment: `@chips` is as an array of `Chip` class instances. `color` is a symbol of types `:white`, `:red`, `:green`, or `:black`.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. It works fine for me, using a Chip class containing a `color` accessor.

Comment: I added some extra code for context. I keep thinking there is something I am overlooking but cannot seem to find it.

Comment: I tried this, adding a line that prints `idx`, and I get 0 as I would expect. Are there any additional differences between [my code](https://gist.github.com/nicolasmccurdy/0a4f18429dbbfb542aa8) and yours?

Comment: I tried the same, works for me too. idx ends up being 0 as expected.

Comment: I think the question is what exactly "always returns nil"? @Pori what are you printing that always results into nil? Are you printing _idx_ or something else?

Comment: `idx` is always nil. I have the chips array as a readable attribute within another class.

Comment: Could it be that _chips_ is empty or doesn't contain an element that fulfills the _index_ predicate?

Comment: Same here, can not replicate this problem.

Comment: I have tests running that show that `chips` does in fact have 100 objects that are _not_ nil. Running Nicolas' script works just fine for me. I cannot seem to spot differences. (Great GitHub icon, by the way).

Comment: @Pori can you edit your answer to correct the syntax highlighting?  I mistakenly thought it was missing an `end`.  I'd do it myself but it doesn't satisfy the character requirement.

Comment: Fixed it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Pori It seems obvious that you need to post your whole program, otherwise this riddle will never be solved ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
chips = [Chip.new(:white), Chip.new(:red), Chip.new(:green), Chip.new(:yellow)]
```

Inside the constructor for another class, I wrote a similar snippet to the one above. It contains a symbol, `:yellow` that was an old color used in the `Chip` class. Turns out that was deprecated.

There is more code later on that utilizes the index assignment I was trying to get working. But, it kept returning `nil` because the method that called it looked something like this:

```
while some_val < another_val
  idx = nil
  color = nil

  if some_val >= SOME_CONST
   color = :black # This one did not exist in the array
  elsif some_val >= SOME_OTHER_CONST
   color = :green
  # ...

  idx = chips.index { |chip| chip.color == color }

  if idx.nil?
    return false
  end

  # ...
end
```

`:yellow` took the place of `:black`, making it absent and therefore created a case that would always return nil because it could never be found.

I realized that when placing my example for the question, `:white` was arbitrary. I never realized that my test code was specifically looking for `:black`.

Thanks for the help everyone. Nudging me further into the code helped pinpoint it.